# Wrong chunk size in RTMP?

Tags: video, h.264, rtmp

I'm working with RTMP parser. My program takes RTMP packets from WireShark capture and save video in a container. But today I'm noticed that some sites send me wrong data.  For example `set chunk size = 2147483647`. When I go to site I can watch this video but my program can't save it (because chunk size is wrong). So, how can I resolve this issue?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer:
"Valid sizes are 1 to 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF) inclusive; however, all sizes greater than 16777215 (0xFFFFFF) are equivalent since no chunk is larger than one
 message, and no message is larger than 16777215 bytes."